# Entity Framework groupby children collection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I use Entity Framework 6, I have such database structure (simplified):

Transactions
- Id
- DateTime
- ...

Products
- Id
- Name

TransactionsItems
- Id
- TransactionId
- ProductId

As you see relation Transaction <-> Product is many to many type.

I don't know how to group transactions by products using LINq - something like

```
transactions.GroupBy(t => t.TransactionsItems.Product)
```

where TransactionsItems property is navigation property generated by entity framework and contains collection of items related to this transaction.

I know I can iterate all products and then search for transactionItems and accumulate data, but I wonder whether is there any simplier method to achieve my goal?

Comment: Many to many relationship in EF do not require you to add _linking_ table to context. Then there will be `Transaction` with `Products` collection and vice versa. And you won't need to group by.

Answer (score 1):

Like @ieaglle said, you don't need a linking table in EF. If however you must use this structure, the following line should work:

```
var result = transactionItems.GroupBy(k => k.ProductID, k => trans
.FirstOrDefault(q => q.TransactionID == k.TransactionID));
```

Edit: Iv'e attached my entire test code:

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
}

class Transaction
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
}

class Connect
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
}
```

And the program itself:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product(){ProductID = 1});
        products.Add(new Product(){ProductID = 2});
        List<Transaction> trans = new List<Transaction>();
        trans.Add(new Transaction(){TransactionID = 10});
        trans.Add(new Transaction(){TransactionID = 20});
        trans.Add(new Transaction() { TransactionID = 50 });
        List<Connect> con = new List<Connect>();
        con.Add(new Connect(){TransactionID = 10, ProductID = 1});
        con.Add(new Connect(){TransactionID = 20, ProductID = 1});
        con.Add(new Connect() { TransactionID = 50, ProductID = 2 });

        var r1 = con.GroupBy(k => k.ProductID, k => trans.FirstOrDefault(q => q.TransactionID == k.TransactionID));
    }
}
```

Comment: I used database first approach. When I delete TransactionItems entity then I have no Products collection inside of Transaction.

My linking table contains also information about quantity and such things so I need this table. I can't understand your code.

Comment: My code groups by the product id within the transactionItems and for each grouping it selects the relevant Transaction objects. Did you try running it?

Comment: I've created a simplified version and it works for me. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: Iv'e attached my entire test code. Please let me know if it is irrelevant to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just got to group by a specific column :

```
transactions.GroupBy(t => t.TransactionsItems.Product.Name)
```